# throw statement is ignored within Nextjs middleware helper

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I am writing middleware code for setting up authentication and token validation in my nextjs app. I am using throw instead of returning value from the helper function.

But throw (last statement) is not working in the following code:

```js
async function validate(request: NextRequest) {
  const tokenid = "test";
  if (tokenid) {
    try {
      // in case of error
      throw new Error("test");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("validate: ", error);
    }
  }
  throw new Error("tokenId validation failed");
}
```

This function is called within another function and where the last statement is simply ignored.

```js
export async function googleAuthValidate(request: NextRequest) {
  let response = NextResponse.next();
  try {
    validate(request);
    console.log("throw didnt go into catch");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    response = NextResponse.rewrite("/unauthorized");
  } finally {
    return response;
  }
}
```

I have created a repository for this issue for easy reproduction: [repo](https://github.com/jsbisht/nextjs-middleware-throw-handling)

Comment: Note that `validate()` is an `async` function but when you call it you don't `await` the result.

Comment: thanks for that. any reason why throw requires await keyword to be present?

Comment: The `await` keyword is there to encapsulate the behavior necessary to handle the Promise returned from a call to an `async` function. Without that, you just get the Promise, and in your example the Promise return value is ignored.